# How to find complete list of warnings in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, static, warnings

I'd like to find the places in my project where '**The static method should be accessed in a 
 static way**' warning raises.

Is there any way of getting the complete list at once ? I did search for a rule set in PMD, but dint find any. So, need help !!!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Click on the small triangle in the upper right corner of the problems view and select "Configure Contents". In that dialog check "Show all items" and uncheck "Use item limits" to show all warnings.

Comment: Thanks daniel. I clicked on that small triangle button and went to 'Preferences'. There is an option to deselect/select the 'marker list', where we can give the limit(default being 100). Am using Eclipse 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Problems view. It should be at the bottom of the screen when using the Java perspective.

Comment: There are more than thousand warnings in the project, so am unable to see this warning, since the problems screen shows the first 100 and last 100 warnings only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would work, but can't you sort the warnings by their actual warning message in the Problems view, so that they'll all end up grouped together? If that doesn't work you could just (temporarily) turn off all the other warnings. Generating a report from [UC Detector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) is another possibility.

Comment: I am unable to sort the warnings, since there are more than 1000 warnings. Is there getting complete list of warnings atleast? It just shows first 100 and last 100 only

Comment: I think you can configure it to show different numbers, and only the first 100 is the default. I don't remember the exact preference but if you go to preferences and type in "warnings" or maybe "problems" you should be able to find it.

Comment: Well I dint find where to set the number of warnings to be shown, but I did is, I went to Preferences/Compiler/Errors-Warnings and set Non-static access to static member to 'Error'. On building the project again, it started showing me the errors. This way I achieved what I needed. Thanks for your help matrix.

Comment: The option to set the limit: Select small triangle in the upper right corner of the problems view, go to preferences, and check(to give our own number of lines)/uncheck the limiter.

Answer (score 0):

Select Markers view, at header of bottom panel for seeing list of warnings or errors